# How to split / explode dataframe dictionary entry into multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I started off with a complex JSON, and after some manipulations I am very close to what I want, The only step I am missing is this:

How to go from output to input, the tricky part is I want to be able to choose which column to flatten

```
[input]
  index  extras                               info
0     a  {'value1': 'one'}                    {'info2': 'two'}
1     a  {'value1': 'one', 'value2': 'two'}   {'info1': 'one', 'info2': 'two'}
2     a  {'value2': 'two'}                    {}
3     b  {'value2': 'two'}                    {'info1': 'one'}
4     b  {}                                   {'info2': 'one'}
5     b  {'value2': 'two'}                    {}

[output]
      index  extras.value1   extras.value2    info
0     a      'one'           Undefined        {'info2': 'two'}
1     a      'one'           'two'            {'info1': 'one', 'info2': 'two'}
2     a      Undefined       'two'            {}
3     b      Undefined       'two'            {'info1': 'one'}
4     b      Undefined       Undefined        {'info2': 'one'}
5     b      Undefined       'two'            {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pop` and `concat`:

```
popped = (pd.DataFrame(df.pop('extras').tolist())
            .fillna('Undefined')
            .add_prefix('extras.'))

pd.concat([popped, df], axis=1)

  extras.value1 extras.value2 index                              info
0           one     Undefined     a                  {'info2': 'two'}
1           one           two     a  {'info1': 'one', 'info2': 'two'}
2     Undefined           two     a                                {}
3     Undefined           two     b                  {'info1': 'one'}
4     Undefined     Undefined     b                  {'info2': 'one'}
5     Undefined           two     b                                {}
```

Comment: I would want to keep the top level col name `extras.value1`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can check with `apply` , this is slow than cold's method

```
df=df.assign(**df.extras.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('extras.'))
```

Comment: This solution saved my day. Thanks a lot @BEN_YO

Comment: @KumarKS yw :-) happy coding